# Java - Unable to inialize object array

Tags: java, arrays

I was not in touch with Java for long time and now I am struggling to initialize the object the Array. Every time it is giving NullPointerException.

```
package RoomExpenses;

import java.util.Scanner;
```

I have put all the main variables outside PSVM

```
public class ExpenseManager 
{
static int n=5;
static Person p[]=new Person[n];
static long average=0,total=0;
```

main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  //  p=new Person[n];

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    initialize();

    System.out.println("Please enter details of all the "+n+" persons");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //p[i]=new Person();
        //It is not allowing me initialize here and giving error. 
        System.out.println("Details of Person No: "+(i+1));
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        p[i].Name=sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter expense done by "+p[i].Name);
        p[i].expense=sc.nextLong();

        p[i].id=i+1;
        p[i].balance=0;
    }
```

calculating average expense

```
    /*    Calculate Average Expense   */
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        total+=p[i].expense;
    }
    average=total/n;




    /*    Calculate Average Expense   */
```

calculating balance each person have. Positive means person should get money from others.

Negative means person should pay money to others

```
    /*    Calculate Balance*/
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p[i].balance=p[i].expense-average;
    }
    /*    Calculate Balance*/
```

Displaying the details of the Persons.

```
    System.out.println("Details of all the persons.");
    System.out.println("Id\t\tName\t\tExpense\t\tBalance");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(p[i].id+"\t\t"+p[i].Name+"\t\t"+p[i].expense+"\t\t"+p[i].balance);
    }







}

public static void initialize() 
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p[i]=new Person(); 
    }
}

class Person
{
    String Name;
    int id;
    long expense,balance;

    Person()
    {
        Name="";
        id=0;
        expense=0;
        balance=0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Always post the *exact* stack trace/error message and explain where/when exactly you encounter your error.  Ideally, if you're posting code, it should be trivial to compile and run it to demonstrate the problem.  The above is not like that and will require the reader to go and stitch together that code you posted.  While just posting links are not encouraged in genral, *also* including a link to say http://pastebin.com/ with the code ready to run would be helpful in this case to save unnecessary effort.

Comment: Please avoid splitting your code into chunks to write text between. It makes it harder to see if these chunks belong together or if there is code missing.

Comment: Sorry W.Prins / Tom. this site was not allowing me to post more lines of the code. and it was asking me to split it.

Comment: Now the issue is resolved. Thanks all for your help. To resolve this I created a new file for Person.Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should un-comment this line :

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    //p[i]=new Person(); // un-comment this line
    System.out.println("Details of Person No: "+(i+1));
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    p[i].Name=sc.nextLine();
    ...
```

You must create a `Person` instance before modifying its members.

With this line commented, `p[i]` is `null`, so `p[i].Name` throws `NullPointerException`.

EDIT :

I just noticed your `Person` class is internal to your `ExpenseManager` class. Change its declaration to `static class Person`, and you will be able to instantiate it without an enclosing instance.

The alternative is to move it outside your `ExpenseManager` class.

Comment: Hello Eran, Yes initally I tried that only. but it is giving error message: "non static vriables cannot be referenced from static content" :(

Comment: for line: p[i]=new Person();

Comment: Now the issue is resolved. Thanks all for your help. To resolve this I created a new file for Person.Java.